# Set cors in my express for node.js already but still give the same error about cors

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, cors

I tried setting cors in my express app already but then it still gives

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/api/login. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.`

I am trying to do an ajax request for my login api for experimenting. If input is correct, it will output "Login Success" if not, "Invalid Login ID or Password".
My code

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var routes = require('./routes');
var cors = require('cors');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:true}));
app.use('/api',routes);
app.use(cors());

/*app.post('/api', function (req, res) {
var data = req.body;
console.log(data);
res.sendStatus(200);
});*/

app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
});
```

This is my ajax request server side code.

```
function login(){

var username = $('#userID').val();
var password = $('#Password').val();
var postData = { "userID": username, "Password": password };
var postJSON = JSON.stringify(postData);

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/api/login", // server url
    type: "POST", //POST or GET
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: postJSON, // data to send in ajax format or querystring format
    dataType : "json",
    success: function(response) {
        alert('success');
        console.log(response);
        $("#result").val(response);
        window.location.replace("http://localhost/index.html");
    },
    error: function(response) {
        alert('error');
    }
    });
  }
```

As for my html code I only

```
<input class="button" type="submit" id="submit" value="Log In" 
onclick="login()"/>
      <div id="result"></div>
```

This is the response I get when observing the network tab in chrome F12.

```
Request URL:http://localhost/
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
userID:SDD
Password:KKK
```

Did I set something wrongly in cors? I already installed in npm and followed the instructions on the npm cors itself but still give this error saying I dont have cors enabled. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

**UPDATE**
After following Abhyudit Jain solution I don't get that error anymore but what I see is this [image: I am not able to identify any error after that with the console only showing abort and my response somehow getting cancelled]

[image]

Any idea as to what kind of error is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you did something wrong. You used cors after you used the routes.

If you move `app.use(cors())` before `app.use('/api', routes)`, it will work fine.

Comment: I updated according to your solution and it worked but now I meet another error instead with no description as to what it is.

Comment: Unless you describe the error, how can I help you? By the way, if your question was answered, please accept this as right answer.

Comment: @OngKongTat you put the symptom here. Try to diagnose the issue by putting console.log() at each step and see where the issue might be - frontend, login route, middleware etc. Then post that as a new question if you're not able to solve the issue. By the way, you didn't post the login route code.